# Failed to open file:gradle

Tags: android

Hello everyone i have gone through all the answers of stackoverflow but not solved my problem. here is my "build.gradle(app)" file.On compiling the gradle files with program i got the error that cann't find the file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.lalit.mapviewtest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Please post the full transcript of wherever you are getting this error message (e.g., Gradle Console, if this is a problem when building your project).

Comment: thanks for response i am getting error in the dependencies injection

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0' error at this line.Gradle console is showing nothing.